# How to migrate a kafka topic to log compaction?

Tags: apache-kafka

we have a Kafka topic, which *cleanup.policy* is currently *delete*. Messages, which have been produced on this topic, have no keys. I'm able to alter the configuration of this topic and it won't accept any new messages without a key, which is reasonable and desired.

I'm wondering what Kafka is going to do with these old keyless messages, though. Are they going to be treated like they have one key, or aren't they going to be affected by the new cleanup policy?

Are there best practices for migrating, I'm not able to find something about that. Is this an unusual use case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some tests in my Kafka Cluster and answering this for future questions:

- Messages without a key are going to be deleted
- If you don't add new messages, you might end up with some of the old messages in the partitions, because they are "in the last segment". They are going to be deleted, when you add new messages

I think I'll introduce a new compacted topic and republish my data to the new one. This causes all consumers to consume a new topic, but this is ok in my case.

Good luck future me